# Deceptive intersection of polar curves

Tags: polar-coordinates

Consider the graphs of $r=\cos 2\theta$ and $r=\cos\theta -1$.

I would like to find all the intersections for the two graphs.

Equating both and solve I only manage to find $(-1,\frac{\pi}{2}),(-1,\frac{3\pi}{2}),(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{\pi}{3}),(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{5\pi}{3})$.

However, there seem to be other intersections as well as the two graphs may not meet at the same value of $\theta$.

Is there a way to solve for the other points of intersection?

Comment: the origin is a point of intersection.

Comment: Other than the origin, there are two more intersections

Comment: There's going to be something in your method that accidentally rejects these other solutions. Unless you show us your working, there's no way of telling how this happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$, 2 points $P_1(x_1,y_1)$ and $P_2(x_2,y_2)$ are equal if and only if there coordinates match exactly ($x_1=x_2, y_1=y_2$). Polar coordinates ($\theta,r$) are different, two points $P_1(\theta_1,r_1),P_2(\theta_2,r_2)$ can represent the same point in the plane without both components matching exactly.

The obvious case is $r_1=r_2, \theta_1-\theta_2=2k\pi, k\in \mathbb Z$. But you know that already and have (as usual) only consisdered $\theta$ in some interval of length $2\pi$, like the usual $[0,2\pi)$.

The first non-trivial case is that any point $(\theta,0)$ represents the origin of the coordinate system. Since $(\frac{\pi}4,0)$ is on the first curve $r=\cos2\theta$ and $(0,0)$ is in the second curve $r=\cos\theta-1$, both curves meet also at the origin.

The second non-trivial case is $\theta_1-\theta_2=\pi, r_1=-r_2$. If you allow negative $r$ (and your formulas will produce negative $r$ for both curves), changing the sign of $r$ means you reflect the point on the origin, resulting in $\theta$ changing by $\pi$. Another way to see that is if you convert back to cartesian coordinates:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
x_1 &=& r_1\cos\theta_1 &=&-r_1(-\cos\theta_1) &=& -r_1\cos(\theta_1-\pi) &=& r_2\cos\theta_2 &=& x_2\\
y_1 &=& r_1\sin\theta_1 &=&-r_1(-\sin\theta_1) &=& -r_1\sin(\theta_1-\pi) &=& r_2\sin\theta_2 &=& y_2\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

So, what needs to be done now?

1) You already solved one case, where $r_1=r_2, \theta_1-\theta_2=2k\pi, k\in \mathbb Z$.

2) The case $r_1=r_2=0$ I solved for you, it's usually very easy.

3) The case $\theta_1-\theta_2=\pi, r_1=-r_2$ is still open. It leads to the equation

$$\cos(2(\theta_2+\pi)) = r_1 = -r_2 =-(\cos\theta_2 - 1)$$

which I trust you can solve yourself, just like in case 1).

EDIT: I wrote that there is small error in your solution, but the error was on my part.

Answer (score 2):

Each non-zero polar coordinate $(r,\theta)$ has an equivalent form $(-r,\theta+\pi)$. Applying this substitution to the two equations yields the new equations $r=-\cos2\theta$ and $r=\cos\theta+1$. Writing $\cos\theta=s$, these become
$$r=2s^2-1\tag1$$
$$r=1-2s^2\tag2$$
$$r=s-1\tag3$$
$$r=s+1\tag4$$
The four combinations $(\{1,2\},\{3,4\})$ of these equations need to be considered separately, and yield the following valid solutions $(r,s)$ where $s\in[-1,1]$:
$$(1,3)\to (-1,0),\left(-\frac12,\frac12\right)$$
$$(1,4)\to\left(\frac{5-\sqrt{17}}4,\frac{1-\sqrt{17}}4\right)$$
$$(2,3)\to\left(\frac{\sqrt{17}-5}4,\frac{\sqrt{17}-1}4\right)$$
$$(2,4)\to(1,0),\left(\frac12,-\frac12\right)$$
Negating both numbers in a pair above yields the same point by the aformentioned equivalence of polar coordinates (for $\cos(\pi+\theta)=-\cos\theta$), so we have the following distinct pairs with $r>0$:
$$(1,0),\left(\frac12,-\frac12\right),\left(\frac{5-\sqrt{17}}4,\frac{1-\sqrt{17}}4\right)$$
The first two pairs above correspond to the four non-origin solutions already found: $(r,\theta)=\left(1,\pm\frac\pi2\right),\left(\frac12,\pm\frac{2\pi}3\right)$. The last one corresponds to the missing two solutions $(r,\theta)=\left(\frac{5-\sqrt{17}}4,\pm\cos^{-1}\frac{1-\sqrt{17}}4\right)$. The last intersection of the two polar curves is the origin.

Answer (score 1):

$\cos 2\theta = \cos\theta - 1\\
2\cos^2 \theta - 1 = \cos\theta - 1\\
\cos\theta(2\cos\theta - 1) = 0\\
\theta = \frac {\pi}{2},\frac {3\pi}{2}, \frac {\pi}{3}, \frac {5\pi}{3}$

However, the curves will also overlap when $r(\theta)$ in one curve equals $-r(\theta + \pi)$ in the other.

$\cos 2\theta = \cos\theta + 1\\
2\cos^2 \theta - 1 = \cos\theta + 1\\
2\cos^2 \theta - \cos\theta - 2$

$\cos \theta = \frac {1 - \sqrt {17}}{4}$

Which will give two more points.

The curves $r = \cos \theta - 1$ and $r=\cos\theta + 1$ are identical curves.

And the curves intersect at $r = 0$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use that $$\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1$$

Comment: I already used that when solving for the four intersections. Just that there are 3 more intersections, one is the origin and two others. How do I find the missing two?